# How to export Quality Profile rules into Excel

Tags: excel, sonarqube

We are using SonarQube 4.5.1 for our projects and are planning to provide list of rules activation/deactivation to end users.

What is best way to export/import within SonarQube in Excel?

There is option of backup in Quality Profile but it did not export description.
I looked directly in the database with rules table, but due to some HTML tag this is not working for delimited with semicolon.

I would also like to know how we can add customized rules to existing set of rules. What is the procedure?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to export to excel for the benefit of your users. Why not simply direct them to the SonarQube interface, where they can browse the rules in your profiles or search them by criteria?
For instance, here are the rules in Nemo's SonarQube Security Way Java profile: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#qprofile=java-java-security-quality-profile-60308|activation=true|languages=java

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

We are going to serve all .Net projects within our organization, say around 50 and around 500 users. 
so we have portal where end user can request to modify quality profile with modification required for given rules

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube interface is really going to be the best referential for your users. Based on the info in your comment, I'd suggest a simple web form rather than trying to construct a spreadsheet.

It may help to know that you can construct the URL to any rule using the repositoryKey and key returned in the XML profile backup:

http://[server]/coding_rules#rule_key=[repositoryKey]:[key]

E.G. https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search?rule_key=csharpsquid%3AS907

The API supports many parameters that are documented here: https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/rules/search (click the Parameters header above the horizontal line to open the descriptions).

For example, the languages parameter makes it possible to search for rules that apply to one or more languages (a comma-separated list). To get the list of all C# rules, you can use https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search?languages=cs

Comment: Thanks G.Ann for your reply.

To modify quality profile, proper approval is needed and rational for the same and then based on given information, management will decide whether quality profile can be customized as per request or it still need further discussion.
So we can not provide direct access to end user to modify quality profile on their own.

By the way, we managed to get information thru Pgadmin tool and accessed to database table called "Rules" and exported required columns and rows for C# language.

Comment: I never meant to suggest users should be given Profile Admin privs. Just that you construct an independent web form for them to use in submitting their profile change requests.

Comment: Hello G.Ann

Sorry for late reply, i was stuck in other priority tasks.

Thanks for your reply, Yes, i know you never said about admin access.

So if we go with independent web form, how can i extract data from Sonar related to C# sonar rules? Similar way i mentioned in my previous post i.e. Extract data from database table

Comment: @Ann 
I try to Get all the java rules https://sonarqube.com/api/rules?language=java and I get "{"errors":[{"msg":"Unknown controller: api"}]}". Is this still possible to get all the rules with one call?

Comment: Check the web service docs: https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/rules/search

Answer (score 1):

To export the Rules on JSON format:

For C++ rules you can use the URL:

```
http://<localhost:<port/>>api/rules/search?languages=c%2B%2B
```

For C rules you can use the URL:

```
http://<localhost:<port/>>api/rules/search?languages=cs
```

Answer (score 0):

After saving result of search API in json file, to cover entirely the question, import of json result in excel can be done with https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: Although links to external resources may be useful, this does not provide an answer. Please make sure the main content of the solution is included directly in the post on SO.

Comment: Solution to export from Sonar was given but import into Excel was not !

As solution was partially covered, I added the last step to do to answer entirely to the question; check the tile : "How to export Quality Profile rules into Excel" (... into Excel)
And not useful to repeat solution already well explain.